# json response renders undefined in console, vue.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I have a simple vue.js app where I am trying to print out some text with typescript. The json response looks like.

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "firstName": "Foo",
            "lastName": "Smith"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Mike",
            "lastName": "vue"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "go",
            "lastName": "lang"
        }
    ],
    "metadata": "none"
}
```

typescript

```
export interface TestResponse {
    firstName:string;
    lastName:string;
}
```

axios call

```
const request: AxiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: url.baseUrl,
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
    },
    //params: {base64_encoded: 'true', fields: 'stdout'},
});

export const api = {

    async getTest() {
        try{
            return await request.get<TestResponse>("/v1/test")
                .then(res => {
                    console.log("lastname " + res.data.lastName);
                    return res.data
                })
        }catch (err) {
            console.log("error" + err);
        }
    },

}
```

However here it always renders undefined. I tried to `TestResponse[]` and `Array<TestResponse>` with no avail.

This should be giving me an array but I get

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')
```

---

```
export default {
    name: "Test",

    setup() {

        const firstName = ref('');
        const lastName = ref('');

        const submit = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await api.getTest()

                if (response != null) {
                    firstName.value = response[0].data.firstName
                    lastName.value = response[0].data.lastName
                    console.log("I am a name " + response.lastName)
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.log('Error while getting the response:', error)
            }
        }

        return {
          firstName,
          lastName,
          submit
        }

    },

};
```

Comment: You're supposed to get TS error because res.data.lastName is wrong, should be res.data.data.lastName. You could just debug res.data and see what it looks like. That you tried wrong types makes no difference because TS types don't exist at runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two issues, first the type of your response object, second the way you execute your request.

About the response object, the content of the response body is located in `res.data` but it seems your API also return a field data, so you might need to do `res.data.data` or update the body returned by your API.
Based on your example json response, the correct Typescript type would be:

```js
export interface TestResponse {
  firtName: string
  lastName: string
}

export interface TestResponseRO {
  data: TestResponse[]
  metadata: string
}
```

If you use `await`, you do not need to use `.then`, you should instead do the following

```js
async getTest() {
  try {
    const res = await request.get<TestResponseRO>("/v1/test");

    console.log(res.data) // Should display '{"data": [your array], "metadata": "none"}'

    return res.data 
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
}
```

If you still have an error, try to execute a request using `curl` or `Postman` to make sure your API is working well.

I also recommend you to use [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) as HTTP client, it's more flexible than `request` in my opinion.

Comment: I am using axios, I updated the question to include the declaration.